# Does TypeScript support namespace?

Tags: namespaces, typescript

As in the title: does TypeScript support namespaces? If so, how do I use them?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Typescript allows to define **modules** closely related to what will be in ECMAScript 6. The following example is taken from the spec:

```
module outer {
    var local = 1;
    export var a = local;
    export module inner {
        export var x = 10;
    }
}
```

As you can see, modules have names and can be nested. If you use dots in module names, typescript will compile this to nested modules as follows:

```
module A.B.C {
    export var x = 1;
}
```

This is equal to

```
module A {
    module B {
        module C {
            export var x = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

What's also important is that if you reuse the exact same module name in one typescript program, the code will belong to the same module. Hence, you can use nested modules to implement hierarchichal namespaces.

Comment: Note that these modules are now referred to as namespaces: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2159

Comment: I wouldn't recommended `namespace` nor mixing it with `module` source code.

Answer (score 28):

As of version 1.5, Typescript supports `namespace` keyword. Namespaces are equivalent to internal modules.

From [What's new in Typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#namespace-keyword):

> Before:
>
> ```
> module Math {
>     export function add(x, y) { ... }
> }
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> namespace Math {
>     export function add(x, y) { ... }
> }
> ```

For defining an internal module, now you can use both `module` and `namespace`.

Comment: Both `module` and `namespace` transpile to the same JavaScript code.

Comment: I wouldn't recommended `namespace` nor mixing it with `module` source code.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a TypeScript namespace example:

```
///<reference path='AnotherNamespace/ClassOne.ts'/>
///<reference path='AnotherNamespace/ClassTwo.ts'/>

module MyNamespace
{
    import ClassOne = AnotherNamespace.ClassOne;
    import ClassTwo = AnotherNamespace.ClassTwo;

    export class Main
    {
        private _classOne:ClassOne;
        private _classTwo:ClassTwo;

        constructor()
        {
            this._classOne = new ClassOne();
            this._classTwo = new ClassTwo();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no 'namespace' keyword, but internal modules (using the 'module' keyword) and external modules (using the 'export' keyword) offer a similar way to partition your code into logical hierarchies.

Comment: since typescript 1.5 there is such a keyword

Comment: I wouldn't recommended `namespace` nor mixing it with `module` source code.

Answer (score 4):

False...

```
module A.B.C {
    export var x = 1;
}
```

is equal to

```
module A {
    export module B {
        export module C {
            export var x = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

because you can write outside the module A :

```
var y = A.B.C.x;
```

But :

```
module A {
    module B {
        module C {
            export var x = 1;
        }
        var y = C.x; // OK
    }
    //var y = B.C.x; // Invalid
}
//var y = A.B.C.x;   // Invalid
```