# Using modules for namespaces, is that OK?

Tags: typescript

I would like to know how advisable is to use (ab)use modules as namespaces in Typescript. Is the following snippet a common practice? Or is there a better way:

```typescript
module Blend {
    export module layout {
        export module container {
            export module box {
                export class Box extends Blend.layout.container.Layout {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Linked question is only relevant if you're using external modules. Note that in TS1.5 you can use `namespace` as an alias for `module`; they really are the same thing. Also, you can write `module Blend.layout.container.box {` to save yourself some tabbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thats fine. You can use nested modules to implement hierarchical namespaces in Typescript.

See also [Does TypeScript support namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737942/does-typescript-support-namespace)